# pass parameter not having to worry about orders exe c#

Tags: c#, .net, parameters, exe

Trying to pass a parameter without having to think about the order of parameters.
The first line is what I want to be able to do and below is what I am able to do.

**What I want where both should give the same result**

```
test.exe -word1 hello -word2 bye
test.exe -word2 bye -word1 hello
```

**What I have**

```
test.exe hello bye

static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            console.line(args[0])
            console.line(args[1])
        }
```

Comment: There are various packages for this sort of thing - https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api is probably where the ecosystem is going.

Comment: Your only options are are to pass a string array or nothing. As a hack, you could pass a string that deserializes to something that has properties you can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume in your example word1 will have the value "hello", but could have any other value and you are interested into that value. With [`Array.IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=netcore-3.1) you can look for the index and then fetch the string with the index one higher:

```
int index1 = Array.IndexOf(args, "-word1");
string word1 = args[index1+1];
int index2 = Array.IndexOf(args, "-word2");
string word2 = args[index2+1];
```

You might consider to check also for the array boundaries (`index1 < args.Length-1`) and that `index1` and `index2` are not -1 and display an appropriate error message if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the string input like so instead:

```
test.exe -word1=hello -word2=bye
test.exe -word2=bye -word1=hello
```

and then you could do something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Single if the param is needed, else SingleOrDefault (to get null if the param. was not found
            var word1 = args.Single(c => c.startsWith("-"+nameof(word1))
                            .Split(new char[] {'='})
                            .Last();
            var word2 = args.Single(c => c.startsWith("-"+nameof(word2))
                            .Split(new char[] {'='})
                            .Last();                            
        }
```

this is pseudo code, i did not run it - just to give you an example.

I wouldn't even bother tho, and just slap in: https://github.com/Tyrrrz/CliFx

Comment: Yeah, caught that too late.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CommandLineApplication` from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils

then you can configure your command line parameters and other available options and use them explicitly later on.

For example:

```
    var app = new CommandLineApplication()
    {
        Description = "CLI tool for copying messages from one queue to another",
        Name = "copy-queue",
    };

    var sourceOption = _app.Option("--source|-s", $"The source queue name", CommandOptionType.SingleValue);
    var destinationOption = _app.Option("--destination|-d", $"The destination queue name", CommandOptionType.SingleValue);
    var profileOption = _app.Option("--profile|-p", $"AWS CLI profile (default: default)", CommandOptionType.SingleValue);
    var regionOption = _app.Option("--region|-r", $"AWS region (default: us-east-1)", CommandOptionType.SingleValue);
    var batchSizeOption = _app.Option("--batch-size|-b", $"Batch size (default: 10)", CommandOptionType.SingleValue);

    _app.HelpOption("--help|-h|-?");

    var name = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName();
    _app.VersionOption("--version", name.Name + " " + name.Version);


    _app.Invoke = () => ExecuteAsync().Result;

    try
    {
        return _app.Execute(args);
    }
    catch (CommandParsingException cpe)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(cpe.Message);
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: I tried to look at the github page it is more complicated than I had hoped.